# How to retrieve inner object values inside a json array

Tags: android, json

I have done coding using fragment.

this my homeFragment

```
res = out.toString();
                        JSONArray arrJsonArray=new JSONArray(res);
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = arrJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Data data=new Data();
                            data.setName(object.getString("title"));
                            data.setMsg(object.getString("slug"));
                            /* for abouve code i am getting data for below code i am not able to retrive the data*/
                            object.getJSONObject("offer_shop_details");
                            data.setOffer(object.getString("time_field_from_sunday"));
                            itemList.add(data);
                        }
```

below is my json. I is jsonArray

i have given one array element of my json.

i need to get the data inside "offer_shop_details" and the above is my logic. help me in finding the correct answer.

the json below if you validate it ll tell invalid. because i have given only a part of it.

```
          [
{
ID: 528,
title: "Buy breakfast meal get free salad",
status: "publish",
type: "offers",
content: "",
parent: 0,
link: "",
date: "2015-03-30T10:25:29+00:00",
slug: "buy-breakfast-meal-get-free-salad-2",
excerpt: null,
meta: {
links: {
self: "",
author: "",
collection: "",
replies: "",
version-history: ""
}
},
offer_shop_details: {
time_field_from: "03:00",
time_field_to: "18:45",
time_field_from_sunday: "10:00",
time_field_to_sunday: "00:00",
time_field_from_monday: "10:00",
time_field_to_monday: "00:00",
time_field_from_tuesday: "10:00",
time_field_to_tuesday: "00:00",
time_field_from_wednesday: "10:00",
time_field_to_wednesday: "00:00",
time_field_from_thursday: "10:00",
time_field_to_thursday: "00:00",
time_field_from_friday: "10:00",
time_field_to_friday: "00:00",
time_field_from_saturday: "10:00",
time_field_to_saturday: "00:00",
afflshop_address: "Manama",
afflshop_website: "",
afflshop_image_id: {
id: "278",
url: ""
}
},
mall_shop_details: false,
author: {
ID: 1,
username: "bm",
name: "bm",
first_name: "",
last_name: "",
nickname: "bm",
slug: "bm",
URL: "",
avatar: "",
description: "",
registered: "2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
meta: {
links: {
self: "",
archives: ""
}
}
},
featured_image: null,
terms: {
offershop: [
{
ID: 29,
name: "Salad boutique",
slug: "salad-boutique",
description: "",
parent: {
ID: 31,
name: "Restaurant",
slug: "restaurant",
description: "",
parent: null,
count: 0,
link: "",
meta: {
links: {
collection: "",
self: ""
}
}
},
count: 1,
link: "",
meta: {
links: {
collection: "",
self: ""
}
}
}
]
}
},
{
ID: 527,
title: "One Full Service Second for Half Price",
status: "publish",
type: "offers",
content: "",
parent: 0,
link: "",
date: "2015-03-30T10:21:17+00:00",
slug: "one-full-service-second-for-half-price-2",
excerpt: null,
meta: {
links: {
self: "",
author: "",
collection: "",
replies: "",
version-history: ""
}
},
offer_shop_details: {
time_field_from_sunday: "10:00",
time_field_to_sunday: "22:00",
time_field_from_monday: "10:00",
time_field_to_monday: "22:00",
time_field_from_tuesday: "10:00",
time_field_to_tuesday: "22:00",
time_field_from_wednesday: "10:00",
time_field_to_wednesday: " 22:00",
time_field_from_thursday: "10:00",
time_field_to_thursday: "22:00",
time_field_from_friday: "10:00",
time_field_to_friday: "22:00",
time_field_from_saturday: "10:00",
time_field_to_saturday: "22:00",
afflshop_address: "Name: Aya EL Baba Email: aya.b@fcc.bh Address: SEEF Location: Adliya",
afflshop_website: "",
afflshop_contact: "+. 973 36 9999 25",
afflshop_image_id: {
id: "279",
url: ""
}
},
mall_shop_details: false,
author: {
ID: 1,
username: "bm",
name: "bm",
first_name: "",
last_name: "",
nickname: "bm",
slug: "bm",
URL: "",
avatar: "",
description: "",
registered: "2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
meta: {
links: {
self: "",
archives: ""
}
}
},
featured_image: null,
terms: {
offershop: [
{
ID: 36,
name: "TONY &amp; GUY",
slug: "tony-and-guy",
description: "TONI&amp;GUY is the most powerful hairdressing brand in the world. The company is constantly evolving artistically and commercially. It offers the best education on the planet and boasts fabulous product ranges and a dynamic and modern image.",
parent: {
ID: 35,
name: "Saloon",
slug: "saloon",
description: "",
parent: null,
count: 0,
link: "",
meta: {
links: {
collection: "",
self: ""
}
}
},
count: 1,
link: "",
meta: {
links: {
collection: "",
self: ""
}
}
}
]
}
},
{
ID: 482,
title: "Sample Offer",
status: "publish",
type: "offers",
content: "",
parent: 0,
link: "",
date: "2015-03-26T10:48:35+00:00",
slug: "sample-offer-10",
excerpt: null,
meta: {
links: {
self: "",
author: "",
collection: "",
replies: "",
version-history: ""
}
},
offer_shop_details: {
afflshop_days: [
"0",
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6"
],
time_field_from: "09:00",
time_field_to: "22:00",
afflshop_address: "New extention Seef Mall, 1st Floor, Manama, Bahrain",
afflshop_website: "",
afflshop_email: "ahmed@goodfood.bh",
afflshop_contact: "3333286",
afflshop_image_id: {
id: "512",
url: ""
}
},
mall_shop_details: false,
author: {
ID: 1,
username: "bm",
name: "bm",
first_name: "",
last_name: "",
nickname: "bm",
slug: "bm",
URL: "",
avatar: "",
description: "",
registered: "2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
meta: {
links: {
self: "",
archives: ""
}
}
},
featured_image: null,
terms: {
offershop: [
{
ID: 62,
name: "Organic Foods and Café",
slug: "organic-foods-and-cafe",
description: "",
parent: {
ID: 31,
name: "Restaurant",
slug: "restaurant",
description: "",
parent: null,
count: 0,
link: "",
meta: {
links: {
collection: "",
self: ""
}
}
},
count: 1,
link: "",
meta: {
links: {
collection: "",
self: ""
}
}
}
]
}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of your JSON string is a JSONObject so use it to parse your JSON and then use [getJSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)) to get your JSON array:

```
res = out.toString();

JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(res);

// And then you can access to your array
JSONArray arrJsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray(rootJsonObject);
```

Comment: my root is JSONArray not JSONObject. i have just put array of 0, above. my json starts with [ braces  and immediately with { this. i cant put the complete link.